How do I test if a population change is statistically significant?
I have data showing different statistics for all parishes in the country for 2014 and 2024 (I actually have data for all the years in between as well, but I am comparing these two years). The data include the percentage of people who are members of the church and the number of weddings held that year. These numbers can be quite small and depend on whether a few families move to or from the parish. So, there might be some random variation from year to year.
I would like to know whether the change observed is likely due to chance or if it is a significant change (so my test hypothesis would be, that there is no change). The problem is that the values from different years are not independent. Is there a simple way to test this?
To clarify, I’m not doing any analysis on these data myself. I’m presenting the data to people who are mostly unfamiliar with math, but who are going to make strategies for the future development of their parish partly based on these numbers. They are likely to overinterpret changes and not take into account, that the change might be caused by random variation. Ideally, I would like to be able to point out those cases where the change is so small/based on so few people (or ceremonies) that they should not consider them.
EDIT:
Based on the comments, I’m going back and forth on different ways to tackle the problem. I might end up doing some kind of trend analysis instead, using all the years available. That would reduce the risk of the chosen years being outliers and therefore getting the wrong impression. But I can’t figure out which test to use, when I have proportions. The tests I have found do not seem to take the sample size into account. Do you have any recommendations?

Unfortunately, 'testing for significance' is not a good (or even coherent) goal. It sweeps under the carpet the important scientific/research goals, based on which one may make different assumptions and use different methods. So if you can edit your question to describe in detail what knowledge you hope to gain, we may be able to advise you on how best to proceed.

I'm leery of using only 2 years when you have 11.  Also, when you have whole populations, the concept of statistically significant becomes rather murky. Finally, I agree with @mkt . Statistical significance requires a hypothesis test.

To elaborate on the comment by mkt, a research goal might be for example if you are trying to show that the % of members has changed over the years, or remained the same. In this case, it's arguable that a test is necessary at all (as Peter Flom says), as apparently you have the data for the whole population. Still, even if you consider your data as a sample of a larger hypothetical population, think hard about the hypothesis you want to test, because with a sufficiently large sample size even the tiniest percentage change will give you a small p-value, if you test for any change.

Thank you for both your comments. I have tried to clarify the purpose of my question. I know it would be better using all of the years, and I might end up having to do so, but I'm really limited by the requirement that I have to convey the results as simple as possible. I can only present the data in a table/plot in a powerpoint, and I can't write much descriptive text as I'm making 1200 autogenerated presentations.

Also, note that if you don't get a small p-value from a statistical test, that doesn't necessarily mean that "it's probably just chance, nothing particular is going on". If a parish with originally 10 members lost half of them in a few years, there might be still some cause for concern, even if a statistical test doesn't return a small p-value. Other people might have additional suggestions, but besides statistical analysis, simply interviewing people who left may be useful to determine if there is some reason to worry.

Thank you @J-J-J. It is really useful. We are of course going to recommend that the parishes use their local knowledge to put the numbers into perspective. I’m going back and forth on different ways to tackle the problem. I might end up doing some kind of trend analysis instead, using all the years available. That would reduce the risk of the chosen years being outliers and therefore getting the wrong impression. But I can’t figure out which test to use, when I have proportions. The tests I have found do not seem to take the sample size into account. Do you have any recommendations?

I added the "time-series" and "trend" tags to your question, to attract the attention of other people who are familiar with this kind of analysis (time series analysis is not a thing I work with often, to be honest).

Thank you again! I've editted the post to include the question about how to test trends.

I think one could derive a test from setting up a demographical model for "essentially no change" and then see (theoretically or experimentally) what distribution of observed changes that would imply and whether the really observed change is significant with respect to that. To me that seems realistic but may involve too much work to be done for you for free by strangers on the internet.

I'm by the way not as negative as some others about applying a statistical test here. If this leads to a non-significant result, this basically means that variation is so low that it cannot be told apart from what would be expected under null model M, which in my view can be informative regardless of whether anybody believes model M to be true.

In addition to the good comments above, I have an issue with the use of "percentages" of parishioners. This percentage can change because eithet the numerator and/or the denominator changed; so a change in percentage is ambiguous. You would be much better off doing your analysis on number of parishioners. Do you have access to it, or can you derive it from the data?

I know that the first step I would take is simply to plot the data (counts !(see earlier comment) of parishioners and weddings) over the 11 years. Do I see any trend, of any kind? If I do, then it is worth identifying this trend, and seeing if it is "significant". But if I do not, I may just have found your answer... In fact, if you attached such a plot to the question, you may get a few pairs of trained eyes to chime in.

I think, rather than testing for significance, you can restate your goal maybe to forecast the number of weddings for each parish. I would suggest a model with a binomial link, with a dataframe where each row is a member of a parish in a particular year. See here https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/logistic-regression-with-glmfamily-binomial.html. Then you can add a coefficient for year, and see if a parish has a positive or negative trend
glm(married ~ 1 + parish + year * parish, family = "binomial")

This is all using the R programming language, which can be recommended for this case, but other statistical environments will have similar functionality available.
One immediate problematic thing here is assuming a linear trend; this will not model a changepoint for example. And also, extrapolating such a trend will lead to nonsensical conclusions, such as a infinite or zero marriage rate in 50 years - depending on the currently estimated trend. But, it is going to be a good starting point.
If you want to make it more advanced / better, you can

do something better for the trend; is there any theory on how the marriage rate is evolving?
make your model "hierarchical" (aka. "random effects"), grouping over the parishes
add additional data that you may have available for the members, first and foremost, if they're married already, perhaps age?


Unfortunately, I only have the aggregated data on parish level. I don't have data for individuals. So for example I know that parish 1 had 254 residents in 2014 and of them 203 where members. That year there were 9 marriages and 21 funerals. And likewise for following years.

I would suggest a small tweak: your model would be better as a GLMM with random effects to account for the non-independence. An even better option would use all years of data, of course, though that would likely be a much more complex model.

You could also drop 1 + parish because that is already captured by year * parish.

Note that @Cristy Bjerg mentioned that the results are intended to be presented to laypeople. I think that answers to this question should take that into account (I don't mean that the methods presented in this answer and comments are incorrect or irrelevant, but adding a suggestion on how to present them to laypeople might be quite useful).

@J-J-J In my opinion the question of method and the question of how to present to laypeople are two different issues, and in my view the question asks for the former, even if the necessity for the latter is part of the background, But for sure the questioner doesn't aspire to teach their audience a statistical method however simple that may be. Saying that "this change cannot be told apart from random variation" may be enough for the laypeople whatever test is used.

By the way, looking only at two years (and interpreting results strictly for the comparison between two years only) there is no issue with linearity. Also the glm directly leads to a statistical test (although the problem with dependence remains).

@CristyBjerg regarding the aggregation; that is still okay, you can just create the rows without any additional information. So each row would be at least year (float or int), married (0/1) and parish (category), with for each parish, a number of anonymous rows with married = 1 and married = 0 so that it works out. Others, thanks for these improvements, I agree with all this.

@Gijs Thank you. For clarification, how many rows would I make for a parish? Because it is the number of weddings performed in the church, and not the number of members getting married. Therefore, making a row per resident would not make sense.

Ah yes that is a sharp comment. Then it's different. The parishes are the rows, the number of members are columns, and the number of weddings is what you are modelling. And the family is going to be Poisson (or negative binomial); a potentially unlimited counting variables, assuming weddings can also involve non-members.
glm(weddings ~ members + parish * year, family = "Poisson").
This will give you a coefficient for year for every parish corresponding to the fitted trend. Random effects model:
glm(weddings ~ (members | parish) + (year | parish), family = "Poisson").

@Gijs Thanks a lot! I will try this.

@mkt I doubt that a random effect will appropriately deal with dependence here, as I don't think this will play out in terms of an additive constant in the linear predictor. It's probably the easiest thing to do and maybe better than nothing, but in this situation I expect that demography can come up with a more realistic  account of the dependence, modelling the population movements explicitly.

@ChristianHennig Yes, I agree. I was thinking of this more and the age structure was definitely the big missing piece. And what I suggested would also not account for the non-trivial spatial structure.
